# How do I select a range of cells depending on number of rows in the sheet?

Tags: excel, row, selection, vba

I currently have multiple data sheets with information in columns A-I in all of them, and I want to select a range of cells in each. Column A varies between 150 rows to 450 rows of data depending on the sheet. I want to select columns A-I but only up through the last row found in column A. I used the last row function:

```
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

How do I get the macro to select columns A-I up through the last row? I want it to function as if it was written:

```
Range("A1:ILastRow").Select
```

where the "LastRow" is the number of the last column.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

... You're EXTREMELY close - just use this:

```
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:I" & LastRow).Select
```

Comment: Just a note - the code above returns last "visible" row. It does not work when you have hidden rows.